# Multi-dimensional tensors as input to rnn in tensorflow (tf.contrib.rnn.RNNCell)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, recurrent-neural-network

From tensorflow documentation about tf.contrib.rnn.RNNCell: "This definition of cell differs from the definition used in the literature. In the literature, 'cell' refers to an object with a single scalar output. This definition refers to a horizontal array of such units."

It seems, that rnn cell only accepts vectors as inputs. However I would like to feed images/videos to an rnn (e.g. [batch size, steps, height, width, channels]). Is there a way to do this using rnn cell and dynamic rnn, or do I have to manually construct an rnn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said RNN only accept as input a Tensor like [batch_size, sequence_lentgh, features].

In order to use RNN from tensorflow you will have to extract the features with a CNN for each frame and convert your CNN output data to a tensor that follows [batch_size, sequence_lentgh, features] shape in order to feed it to the RNN.

Comment: Thank you. Since I am using fully convolutional networks, I won't be able to use it then. I'm pretty sure rnn cell doesn't accept None type dimensions either, even if I would reshape the inputs to images again and use convolutions inside the cell...

Comment: It would be nice to have a more abstract cell type built into tensorflow to use together with dynamic rnn.